# update the quantity and price of of OrderItemSummary

Tags: commerce-cloud, connect-api, b2b-commerce

It possible to update the quantity and price of of OrderItemSummary or add new product to order and its order product summary once order is created using connectAPI in commerce cloud. As we have split shipment so that each shipment have different pricing each time its when the product is shipped.

As per commerce stand point we don't see any connectAPI to update or add new product to created order. I saw [add products](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.flow_ref_elements_om_actions_add_ois.htm&type=5) but this is a flow i am trying to find any connectAPI alternative to this flow.

Our client need is, when they ship a product they freight cost, Charge for Delivery and multiple service customer can select before placing the order. Once order is placed all the selected service are mapped into order as different product order line items.

This works fine with if warehouse have products in stock. Now the problem is when warehouse don't have products in stock customer can ask for partial shipment. In this case the product will be shipped based on availability, so once the product is available in warehouse the inside sales user can ship the product.

eg: If the customer ask is 100. Once 20 the product is available he/she can ship only 20 ant once. Next time its 5 then he/she can ship the available 5 to customer.

In the above example we don't know in advance how the split going to happen. Now client need to have freight cost, Charge for Delivery and multiple service which he selected while ordering to be added as new product when each time fulfilment order is created.

Like when customer placed the order of 100 products at the time they selected 3 service. Now we have 4 products in order line items - 100 products + 3 services. Now if i ship this 100 products as 5 different shipments then it should have

20 products + 3 service
20 products + 3 service
20 products + 3 service
15 products + 3 service
5 products + 3 service

Now the order line and order summery line need to be updated with 5 split of 100 products and 15 services associated to it. We are able to create partial allocated fulfilment to the each split of product but the not able to add service to it.

Do anyone know how can we achieve it with connectAPI.

I tried to update the price keeping the quantity as same using ConnectApi.AdjustOrderItemSummaryInputRepresentation but this will only update the price with -ev price.

Trying to use OrderItemSummaryInputRepresentation, this is also not working getting error method not found.

```
ConnectApi.OrderItemSummaryInputRepresentation orderItemSummaryInput = new 
ConnectApi.OrderItemSummaryInputRepresentation();
orderItemSummaryInput.orderItemSummaryId = '10uxxxxxxxxx';
orderItemSummaryInput.quantity = 3;
ConnectApi.addOrderItemSummary(orderSummaryInput);
ConnectApi.OrderItemSummaryCreation.updateOrderItemSummary(orderItemSummaryInput);
```